# No Data Received ERROR for mysqli free result

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am using OOP concept in order to connect to my database using mysqli but here I am getting an error as ***"database query out of sync you cannot run this command"*** that is why I used mysqli free result and now I am getting no data received as the output. what might be the mistake ?

Below is my database connection class

```
class MySQLDatabase{
private $connection;
public $last_query;
private $magic_quotes_active;
private $real_escape_string_exists;

function __construct()
{
    $this->open_connection();
    $this->magic_quotes_active = get_magic_quotes_gpc();
    $this->real_escape_string_exists = function_exists( "mysqli_real_escape_string" );
}


public function open_connection()
{
    $this->connection=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME) ;
    mysqli_set_charset($this->connection,"utf8");
    if(!$this->connection)
     {
         die("database connecetion failed".mysqli_error($this->connection));
     }
}

public function close_connection()
{
    if(isset($this->connection))
    {
        mysqli_close($this->connection);
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}

public function fetch($result_set)
{
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
}

public function query($sql)
{
  $this->last_query=$sql;
  $result=$this->connection->query($sql);

    if(!$result)
    {
        die("database query failed ".mysqli_error($this->connection));
    }
    return $result;
}

public function free_result($result)
{
    return $this->free_result($result);
}
}
$database=new MySQLDatabase();
```

And this is how I call my procedure but it gives output as no data received I do not know what is the problem

```
    $qryCallImgProc = "CALL description (".$postId.","."@commentOutput,@likeCount,@commentCount)";
    $exeCallIgProc = $database->query($qryCallImgProc);
    while($row = $database->fetch($exeCallIgProc))
    {
        print_r($row);
    }  

    $database->free_result($exeCallIgProc);
    $database->close_connection();

    $qryLikeCount = "SELECT * from user";
    $exeLikeCount = $database->query($qryLikeCount);        
    while ($fetchDetails = $database->fetch($exeLikeCount)) {
         print_r($fetchDetails);
     }
```

Comment: Your `free_result()` method is calling itself.

Comment: It works when i replaced $this->free_result($result); with  mysqli_free_result($reult) but when I am calling my procedure @commentOutput is a outpout parameter and it gives va;ue as null i checked running in workbench value of comment output is not null

Answer (score 0):

I have no enough reputation. so i can't add a comment.

I guess your procedure have no data to return.

you can try to add

```
select 'flag'
```

at the end of your procedure .

EDIT:

I made a procedure Test like this:

```
create PROCEDURE test_procedure(
       OUT totalCount INT
)
BEGIN
  select 1 into totalCount;
  select totalCount;
end
```

It's work fine.

OR  you may use this:

```
$sql = $mysqli->query("call test_procedure(@output)");
$results = $mysqli->query ("select @output as totalCount");
```

hope may help you.

Comment: same thing i tried there only i did not get any data after selecting the query from user

Comment: @user3622633  I run your code ,it's work fine.  Except the free_result(),it calling itself.